# Rails::Paying directly to customer's bank account

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, payment

I have been using `Stripe` as a payment method. I need to implement ACH to pay back to the customer's bank account.

Here's the summarized business model.

- We sell recurring subscriptions to our customers
- With every subscription we deposit some amount as rewards in their account
- At any point of time they can claim their reward money
- We ask them if they want to get paid via check or ACH

Paying to customer via check has been completed.

For ACH, I talked to Stripe and came to know that Stripe only accept payments, but it does not hold funds and exchange them with other people.

I researched and found out that `Paypal` does this.

Is there any other way?

Thanks